# How to prevent having to re-login to ASP.NET web apps after a code change

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I dislike it when I lose the session state of my ASP.NET web app when changing code.

Losing the session state means I have to log in over and over again. It's annoying.

Is there anyway I can reconfigure my app so that I can make changes to code and not have to re-authenticate to view those changes?

(I know that changing .ASPX files does this fine. My concern is over App_Code and Bin compiled code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder what will happen if you will store session state in [StateServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx). Maybe it will work ( I will be surprised if it does).

Comment: This seems very promising. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately changes in the web.config or in dll's in the bin folder will cause an application reload and there is nothing you can do about it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a developer environment you can try disabling logging into the site, or when the site checks for authentication just return your default authentication. For production, a StateServer will help as Igal pointed out.

One last option, store the login information in Session, but as a backup to that use a login table in your database to be able to restore a user's authentication status from a cookie. Obviously, consider security implications.

Answer (score 1):

By changing your StateServer to use your machine (enabling the ASP.NET State Service), you won't lose your login.